# Convert seconds since 1980 in DB2

Tags: timestamp, db2

I'm looking for a way to convert seconds since 1980 to DB2 TIMESTAMP using SQL, DB2 functions, column data type - whatever works.
Is that possible?

Thank you

Comment: Since `'1980-01-01'`?  Are you sure it's not the Unix Epoch (`'1970-01-01'`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMP ('1980-01-01-00.00.00.000000') + X SECOND
    FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1; 


SELECT TIMESTAMP ('1980-01-01-00.00.00.000000') + 6000000 SECOND 
    FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1;
1980-03-10 10:40:00
```

Answer (score 0):

How much precision do you need?  This should convert your value to a date (assuming that your date format is in sec_value):

```
date(sec_value / 86400 + days('1980-01-01'))
```

If you need precision beyond that, it wouldn't be so hard to roll your own math to get the hours and seconds.  A quick search didn't turn up any built-in functionality that does this.

Comment: This only gives me the date, not the time.